# UIRefreshControl with a UITableView (not a UITableViewController) very difficult to refresh

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, ios6

if i add a UIRefreshControl inside a TableView (not a TableViewController), a little smaller, i can't get the refresh activated cause the table hasnt the height that expected, is there any way to modify the sensivity of UIRefreshControl?

[image]

I have to use another finger when i arrive to the bottom of the uitableview, and continue getting to the bottom.

Comment: I think it would be better to use a different type of control to refresh the table if it is too small to use a pull to refresh control.

Comment: I'm condiering inserting a button on top of the table, but is so sick i cant set a sentivity or something like this to refresh the table